# Call a method in the custom view from MainActivity.Java

Tags: java, android, methods, view, graphics2d

I have created a custom view and it has been added to the layout.

```
    <com.example.moynul.myapplication.Draw
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
    />
```

From doing this I do not need to instantiate my Draw class in the MainActivity class.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

However this has limitations, since I cannot call a method in the Draw class.

```
public void buttonOnClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button:
            //call a method in the Draw class 
            break;
    }
}
```

I have tried turning my Draw (that extends view) in to a static class, and turning the method I want to access in a public static method. But the `invalidate()` does not like this.

My next attempt was to create a button on the custom view class via the GUI builder. It appears that you cannot make a button a child object of a custom view object.

My question: How can I access a method in my Draw class from the main class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reference your `Draw` class create global variable  in your `MainActivity`

```
Draw myDraw;
```

Next, set it in your `onCreate`

```
myDraw = (Draw) findViewById(R.id.view);
```

Finally, call it in your `buttonOnClick`

```
case R.id.button:
    myDraw.method();
    break;
```

**OR** If you only want to reference the variable in the `buttonOnClick` you can just do something like this

```
case R.id.button:
    ((Draw) findViewById(R.id.view)).method();
    break;
```

Comment: myObject= (Object) findViewById(R.id.objectDrawnOnGUI); || So this can work to reference anything on the device screen?  So if I have a slider, then Slider slider = (Slider) findViewById(R.id.mySlider); ? The code works well.

Comment: Aah I see. It's very simple to how game engines works, referencing game objects via code. Excellent information.

Answer (score 2):

You could instante the Draw class like this

```
Draw mDraw = (Draw) findViewById(R.id.view);
mDraw.myMethod();
```